# jquery datepicker not working with jsp page without html tags

Tags: jquery

i am trying to use a jquery datepicker in a jsp page with no html.

// all imports using link and script for jquery

```
<h:form id="formid">
<t:div id="datepicker" forceid="true" class="demo">
<f:view>
<h:outputText value="Select date" />
<h:inputText id="datepicker"/>
</t:div>
</f:view>
</h:form>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({showon: 'button', 
buttonImageonly: true});
});
</script>
```

The problem is with the id and the script.
Please share a similar full source code.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Javascript at all... `#datepicker` is just sitting out there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your jsp page generates the proper HTML, your jQuery syntax is wrong. Try:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
    showOn: 'button', 
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly selecting the datepicker textbox. It should be something like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ showOn: button, buttonImageOnly: true });
```

Also note that *showOn* and *buttonImageOnly* must be properly camelCased. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you getting an error messages in your browser console (such as Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools)? Are you able to trace through the code at all? What sort of output is being produced?

Comment: the actual code is at my workplace but the output is just a "select date" text followed by an input text box.

Comment: @akhileshagupta : hard to say without seeing 1) more code or 2) a functional example.